# Can someone help me understand the exact working of this configuration of a Colpitt's oscillator?

Tags: transistors, rf, oscillator, resonance

So I came across this Collpitt's oscillator in a research paper that I am thinking of implementing but it looks quite different from other configurations and I would really appreciate some help understanding it.

These are my questions specifically:

1. Where is the tank circuit? Which capacitors are participating?
2. Where is the capacitor divider and where is the feedback to the transistor?

[image]

I came across this in a research paper which claimed that inductively coupling another tank circuit with the oscillator increases the emitter current with maximum current at resonant frequency. Can someone also help me understand the reason for this? This is the complete picture with the inductively coupled tank circuit.

[image]

[This is the link to the paper if anyone is interested.](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8846110)

Answer (score 2):

> Where is the tank circuit? Which capacitors are participating?

In AC signal analysis the DC supply appears as a short circuit, so you can imagine the positive supply rail as being connected to ground. The tank appears here:

[image]

The coupling capacitor (the unlabeled one) should have a relatively large capacitance compared to C1, C2 and Cvar. The capacitance of the tank is therefore determined by the series-parallel combination of C1, C2 and Cvar.

> 2. Where is the capacitor divider and where is the feedback to the transistor?

Between C1 and C2.

> I came across this in a research paper which claimed that inductively coupling another tank circuit with the oscillator increases the emitter current with maximum current at resonant frequency. Can someone also help me understand the reason for this? This is the complete picture with the inductively coupled tank circuit.

I'm not sure of the exact mechanism in this circuit, but I'm pretty sure it has the same operating principle of a "grid dip meter". Through magnetic coupling the external LC-tank will absorb energy from the oscillator at the resonant frequency of the tank. So if the oscillator and tank are set to the same frequency you'll see a decrease in the output power of the oscillator. A grid dip meter is a tunable oscillator with a power meter. You can find the resonant frequency of an LC-tank by adjusting the frequency of the oscillator until the meter indicates you've hit a local minimum.

Comment: Wow this helped a lot!! I can't thank you enough!!